# How can I use Google reCaptcha div using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need to create a function in javaScript that will generate the Google ReCaptcha.
basically I need to convert this code in javaScript

```
  <head>
    <title>reCAPTCHA demo: Simple page</title>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="?" method="POST">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key"></div>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying but pretty confused about this, please help.

```
value: function() {

        const input_group = $(document.createElement('div'));
        const input_group_addon = $(document.createElement('span'));
        input_group.addClass('g-recaptcha');
        input_group_addon.addClass('input-group-addon');
      }
```

Comment: Do you see any messages on the browser console? Don't forget to replace `data-sitekey="your_site_key"` with your actual site key.

Comment: Yeah, I have my key, But I haven't convert it in javascript yet, after that I'll replace it

Comment: What about making it hidden initially then show it later with JavaScript?

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to have an option for the user so that they can decide they want the captcha in their form or not, in that case, I need to show the captcha while designing the form

Comment: The captcha exists so automatically sending the form with a bot is not possible. Why do you annoy people with a captcha when the bot can opt out to use it?